# How can I make it clear for our users that Logo button is also a Back button?

Tags: back-button

Currently, my team is designing a Shopify-model website which basically looks a lot like Shopify.

And here's the problem.

When our users use the website builder and try to go back to the main admin page, they find it pretty confusing whether they should hit the logo button on the top-left of the site. They're afraid this button will lead them back to the homepage of the website, not the admin page.

My question is, how can I make it more clear for them about the button, or should I make a back button knowing the logo's staying fixed on the top-left?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a separate header for the website builder which will have back navigation button. It should be separate from the theme header which currently consists of the theme logo and other navigation buttons.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies with the logo, it's synonymous with back to homepage. I would recommend breadcrumbs or an additional nav like the above answer.